# Stop users entering my competitions more than once

Tags: asp.net, facebook

I'm having a problem with my Facebook competition where users are entering multiple times. The required fields to enter are first name, last name and email. They can not enter the same email more than once, but they are just using different email addresses. I can not delete their entries however because there is no way to "prove" that it's the same person, even though it's dead obvious (exact same first and last name, all entries within 30 seconds of one another).

Our terms and conditions say that only one entry is allowed per person, per competition but apart from the email validation I can't find a way to enforce this.

When a user likes our page (which is required to enter the competition) is the ID of that user available from the signed request? Would it be within the Facebook guidelines to store this ID along with their entry details?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, you need to authorize the users then you get the Facebook ID.

You then can display a diffrent page as you know this user already taken part in the competition - so you dont give them the change to submit more than once for one Facebook ID.

as this will probably to late know, you can store a cookie. but be aware that users can delete this cookie.

Comment: What do you mean by authorize the users? My competition is a very simple page that just takes the signed_request object that facebook give me on it's post request, then in decodes it and decides if the user likes the page or not.

Comment: Nevermind I just read about what you mean on this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/ seems like that's the only way to go :( Thanks!